# How to travel between Macau Peninsula and Taipa?

Tags: china, macau

What is the best way to get from Macau Peninsula to Taipa and vice versa? Also, is it possible to do that late (say around 1am)?

Comment: There is a nightbus (N2) that goes every 15 minutes. http://www.secretmacau.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/busroute_N2.pdf Or you can just take a taxi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to just take a taxi. It's a pain to deal with buses in Macao.

Alternatively, if your destination is close to Cotai, maybe consider taking a casino shuttle.